# Classic ASP create parameter MSSQL query syntax not correct

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm creating an interface page which will pull response.querystring in for the person_id and then use that in a query as a parm to look up information.   The below is not working but when I hard code the ID it works.   Something is off on the syntax.

```
dim id
dim conn
dim cmdQuery
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Const adVarChar=200
Const adInteger = 3

set conn = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")     
conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
    "SERVER=xxx.xx.x.xxx,xxxx;" & _
            "UID=sa;" & _
            "PWD=sa;" & _
            "DATABASE=person"

id = 1019438
set cmdQuery = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set prm = cmdQuery.CreateParameter("ID", adInteger, 1, , )
With cmdQuery
     Set .ActiveConnection = conn
     .CommandType = adCmdText
     .NamedParameters = true
     Fix:  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prm, adInteger,1, 15, id)
     .CommandText = "SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM person WHERE ID = ?"
     .Parameters.Append prm
End With

set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set rs.Source = cmdQuery
rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
rs.Open
```

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help.  What did you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: Okay.    Solved it...

Comment: .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prm, adInteger,1, 15, id)  Did the trick.

Comment: It was causing a server error.   Seems I needed to remove the quotes on the parm name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dim id
dim conn
dim cmdQuery
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Const adVarChar=200
Const adInteger = 3

  set conn = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")     
  conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
            "SERVER=xxx.xx.x.xxx,xxxx;" & _
            "UID=sa;" & _
            "PWD=sa;" & _
            "DATABASE=person"

  id = 1019438
  set cmdQuery = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

  Set cmdQuery.ActiveConnection = conn
  cmdQuery.CommandType = adCmdText
  cmdQuery.NamedParameters = true
  cmdQuery.CommandText = "SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM person WHERE ID = ?"
  cmdQuery.Parameters.Append cmdQuery.CreateParameter("ID", adInteger, 1, 255, Request("person_id"))

  set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  set rs.Source = cmdQuery
  rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
  rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
  rs.Open
```